# Why does my image in the title bar not work?

Tags: html, css

I have a Website and I've added the following code attempting to add an Image in the Title Bar (https://i.stack.imgur.com/y9vQt.png)

```
<link rel="icon" href="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/1302768002652405760/BMzYV07a_200x200.jpg">
```

When I go to the website it does not show the Image I picked to show, It's just the default one.

My Website: https://rebelcownews.com

Full Code:

HTML:

```
<DOCTYPE! html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <link rel="icon" href="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/1302768002652405760/BMzYV07a_200x200.jpg">
    <title>
            Rebel Cow News
  </title>
  <script data-ad-client="ca-pub-1934423489228120" async src="https://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.7/js/all.js">
  </script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" />
  <script>
    function openSlideMenu(){
      document.getElementById('menu').style.width = '250px';
      document.getElementById('content').style.marginLeft = '250px';
    }
    function closeSlideMenu(){
      document.getElementById('menu').style.width = '0';
      document.getElementById('content').style.marginLeft = '0';
    }
  </script>
</head>
<body>
<!--Top Nav-->
  <div id="content">

    <span class="slide">
      <a href="#" onclick="openSlideMenu()">
        <i class="fas fa-bars"></i>
      </a>
    </span>
      <div id="menu" class="nav">
        <a href="#" class="close" onclick="closeSlideMenu()">
          <i class="fas fa-times"></i>
        </a>
        <a href="index.html" target="_blank">Home</a>
        <a href="about.html" target="_blank">About</a>
        <a href="sources.html" target="_blank">Sources</a>
        <a href="archive.html" target="_blank">Archive</a>
        <a href="contact.html" target="_blank">Contact</a> 
        <a href="feedback.html" target="_blank">Feedback</a>
        <a href="covid19.html" target="_blank">COVID-19</a>
      </div>
<!-- Headline -->
<div class="img-with-text">
  <div class="rowheadline">
    <div class="columnheadline">
      <a href=https://www.foxnews.com/politics/trump-discharged-from-walter-reed-returns-to-white-house " target="_blank"><img src="https://external-content.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.dailyherald.com%2Fstoryimage%2FDA%2F20201005%2FNEWS%2F201009673%2FEP%2F1%2F1%2FEP-201009673.jpg%26updated%3D202010051811%26imageversion%3DFacebook%26exactH%3D630%26exactW%3D1200%26exactfit%3Dcrop%26noborder&f=1&nofb=1" alt="Error 404" style="width:100%">
       <p style="text-align:center;"><a href=https://www.foxnews.com/politics/trump-discharged-from-walter-reed-returns-to-white-house " target="_blank">Trump Returns To White House After Being Hospitalized</a></p>
      </div>
  <div class="img-with-text">
    <div class="columnheadline">
      <a href=https://www.zerohedge.com/political/trump-mulls-nationwide-address-insists-americans-must-learn-live-covid " target="_blank"><img src="https://pbs.twimg.com/card_img/1313473301973528581/J9Py42sg?format=jpg&name=small" alt="Error 404" style="width:100%">
       <p style="text-align:center;"><a href=https://www.zerohedge.com/political/trump-mulls-nationwide-address-insists-americans-must-learn-live-covid " target="_blank">32 Have COVID in White House Outbreak</a></p>
    </div>
</div>
  <!--Row 2-->
  <div class="img-with-text">
    <div class="rowmain">
      <div class="columnmain">
          <a href=https://www.newsmax.com/us/puerto-rico-governor-endorsement-republican/2020/10/06/id/990681/ " target="_blank"><img src="https://img-s-msn-com.akamaized.net/tenant/amp/entityid/BB19LCTB.img?h=450&w=799&m=6&q=60&o=f&l=f&x=545&y=149" alt="Error 404" style="width:100%">
         <p style="text-align:center;"><a href=https://www.newsmax.com/us/puerto-rico-governor-endorsement-republican/2020/10/06/id/990681/ " target="_blank">Governor Of Puerto Rico Endorses Trump</a></p>
          </div>
    <div class="img-with-text">
      <div class="columnmain">
        <a href=https://www.breitbart.com/politics/2020/10/06/donald-trump-ends-negotiations-with-nancy-pelosi-on-coronavirus-relief/ " target="_blank"><img src="https://i.insider.com/5f47e50edb1ed000297144e5?width=900&format=jpeg&auto=webp" alt="Error 404" style="width:100%">
         <p style="text-align:center;"><a href=https://www.breitbart.com/politics/2020/10/06/donald-trump-ends-negotiations-with-nancy-pelosi-on-coronavirus-relief/ " target="_blank">Trump ends negotiations with Pelosi on COVID Relief until after the Election</a></p>
      </div>
</div>
  <!--Row 3-->
    <div class="img-with-text">
      <div class="rowmain2">
        <div class="columnmain2">
            <a href=https://justthenews.com/politics-policy/elections/new-jersey-man-receives-ballot-addressed-his-mother-who-died-11-years-ago " target="_blank"><img src="https://justthenews.com/sites/default/files/styles/hero/public/2020-10/GettyImages-1251299490.jpg?h=af5ef61d&itok=5XHL0MJy" alt="Error 404" style="width:100%">
           <p style="text-align:center;"><a href=https://justthenews.com/politics-policy/elections/new-jersey-man-receives-ballot-addressed-his-mother-who-died-11-years-ago " target="_blank">New Jersey man receives ballot addressed to his mother who died 11 years ago</a></p>
        </div>
      <div class="img-with-text">
        <div class="columnmain2">
          <a href=https://www.dailywire.com/news/yahoo-reporter-yells-at-sick-president-do-you-think-you-might-be-a-super-spreader " target="_blank"><img src="https://static01.nyt.com/images/2020/10/05/world/05-dc-virus-trump1/05-dc-virus-trump1-jumbo.jpg?quality=90&auto=webp" alt="Error 404" style="width:100%">
           <p style="text-align:center;"><a href=https://www.dailywire.com/news/yahoo-reporter-yells-at-sick-president-do-you-think-you-might-be-a-super-spreader " target="_blank">Reporter yells to Trump "Do You Think You Might Be A Super Spreader?"</a></p>
        </div>
      </div>
  <!--Row 4-->
  <div class="img-with-text">
    <div class="rowmain3">
      <div class="columnmain3">
          <a href=https://www.msn.com/en-us/news/politics/michelle-obama-calls-trumps-actions-%E2%80%9Cracist%E2%80%9D-in-new-campaign-video/ar-BB19LFki " target="_blank"><img src="https://images.dailycaller.com/image/width=960,height=411,fit=cover,f=auto/https://cdn01.dailycaller.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/10/Untitled-design-4-scaled.jpg" alt="Error 404" style="width:100%">
         <p style="text-align:center;"><a href=https://www.msn.com/en-us/news/politics/michelle-obama-calls-trumps-actions-%E2%80%9Cracist%E2%80%9D-in-new-campaign-video/ar-BB19LFki " target="_blank">Michelle Obama says Trump's actions are 'Racist' in Joe Biden Campaign Video</a></p>
      </div>
    <div class="img-with-text">
      <div class="columnmain3">
        <a href=https://www.theepochtimes.com/cruz-republicans-appear-to-have-enough-votes-to-confirm-amy-coney-barrett_3528450.html " target="_blank"><img src="https://img.theepochtimes.com/assets/uploads/2020/10/06/sen-ted-cruz-700x420.jpg" alt="Error 404" style="width:100%">
         <p style="text-align:center;"><a href=https://www.theepochtimes.com/cruz-republicans-appear-to-have-enough-votes-to-confirm-amy-coney-barrett_3528450.html " target="_blank">Ted Cruz Says Republicans Have Enough Votes to Confirm Amy Coney Barrett</a></p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
  <footer>
  <div class="footer">
    &copy; 2020 Rebel Cow News </p>
  </div>
  </footer>
  </div>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
/* Top Nav */
body {
  font-family: 'Lucida Console', sans-serif;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  background-color: #222;
}
.nav {
  height: 100%;
  width: 0;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #222;
  opacity: .9;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  padding-top: 60px;
  transition: 0.7s;
}
.nav a {
  display: block;
  padding: 20px 30px;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #FFF;
}
.nav a:hover {
  color: #000;
  transition: 0.1s;
}
.nav .close {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 22px;
  margin-left: 50px;
  font-size: 45px;
}
.slide a {
  color: #FFF;
  font-size: 45px;
}
#content {
  padding: 20px;
  transition: margin-left 0.7s;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
}
/* Footer */
footer {
  font-family: 'Lucida Console';
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  background-attachment: scroll;
  background-position: 0% 0%;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0pt;
}
/* Main Headlines */
/* Text under Image */
.img-with-text {
  text-align: justify;
  width: 100%;
}
.img-with-text img {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
/* 25% four, 50% two, 75% one */
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.columnheadline {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  padding: 5px;
  font-size: 25px;
  font-family: 'Lucida Console', sans-serif;
}
.rowheadline::after {
  content: "";
  clear: both;
  display: table;
}
/* Hyperlink Colors */
      a {
        color: #FFF;
}
/* Main Stories */
.columnmain {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 5px;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: 'Lucida Console', sans-serif;
}
.rowmain::after {
  content: "";
  clear: both;
  display: table;
}
.columnmain2 {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  padding: 5px;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: 'Lucida Console', sans-serif;
}
.rowmain2::after {
  content: "";
  clear: both;
  display: table;
}
.columnmain3 {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  padding: 5px;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: 'Lucida Console', sans-serif;
}
.rowmain3::after {
  content: "";
  clear: both;
  display: table;
}
/* About Page */
.about {
  color: white;
  font-size: xx-large;
  font-family: 'Lucida Console';
  text-align: center;
}
/* Optimize for all Devices */
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .columnheadline {
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 5px;
    font-size: 25px;
    font-family: 'Lucida Console', sans-serif;
  }
  .rowheadline::after {
    content: "";
    clear: both;
    display: table;
  }
  .columnmain {
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 5px;
    font-size: 25px;
    font-family: 'Lucida Console', sans-serif;
  }
  .rowmain::after {
    content: "";
    clear: both;
    display: table;
  }
  .columnmain2 {
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 5px;
    font-size: 25px;
    font-family: 'Lucida Console', sans-serif;
  }
  .rowmain2::after {
    content: "";
    clear: both;
    display: table;
  }
  .columnmain3 {
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 5px;
    font-size: 25px;
    font-family: 'Lucida Console', sans-serif;
  }
  .rowmain3::after {
    content: "";
    clear: both;
    display: table;
  }
}
/* Optimize */
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
.optimize { 
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 5px;
  font-size: 55px;
  font-family: 'Lucida Console', sans-serif;
}
}
.optimize {
  font-size: 35px;
  color: white;
}
```

Any help on this would be amazing :)

Answer (score 0):

Your link has a

`display: none;`

in user agent stylesheet.

Try adding a display property to the link in your css.

Comment: I don't see a display: none in the stylesheet what do you mean by add a display property to the link

Answer (score 0):

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/jpg" href=”https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/1302768002652405760/BMzYV07a_200x200.jpg”/>
```

if still not working, you must put that image to directory e.g assets, and `href` will be `href="/assets/favicon.jpg"/`